# Handling standard array structure in postgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have column "session" in table "A" which looks like this

| session |
| --- |
| [1,3,5,2] |
| [5,1,3,2] |

values in rows saved as VARCHAR, but i want to cast it to array and do some operations on values inside the array

is there a way a to cast those to array? , thank you

Comment: That's not a "standard array" structure for Postgres. Array constants are denoted by curly braces in Postgres, e.g. `'{1,2,3}'`, so you can't cast it to an array. It looks like JSON though, so it could be cast to a JSON value. Which operations exactly do you want to use? Arrays in JSON aren't as flexible as native arrays to a certain extent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace your brackets `[]` to braces `{}` to make it a standard `array` type. then cast it to `int[]`.

```
select unnest(replace(replace(session, '[', '{'), ']', '}')::int[])
```

Comment: Instead of two `replace()` calls you can also use `translate('[1,3,5,2]', '[]', '{}')`